# Having trouble adding methods

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Add three methods, one that will return the maximum value in the array (FindMax), one that will return the minimum value in the array (FindMIn) and one that will return the average of the values in the array (FindAvg).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class methods {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [] numbrs;
        numbrs = new int[25];
        int i = 0;
        System.out.println();
        populateArray(numbrs, numbrs.length);
        System.out.println("\n********** the array reversed is **********\n");
        for (i = numbrs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        System.out.println(numbrs[i]);

        System.out.println("\n***** end of Array01.java *****");
      } // end of main method

/* ********************************************************
   Pre Condition: an array of n integers where n is given.

   Post Condition: an array populated with randomly
   generated integers in the range of 1 to limit
   specified by the user.
   ******************************************************** */

    public static void populateArray(int [] arry, int lm) {
        Scanner kBd;
        int lim = 0;
        kBd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the upper limit of random numbers...");
        lim = kBd.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        int x = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < lm; i++) {
        arry[i] = getRandomInt(lim);
        System.out.println(arry[i]);
    }
    } // end of populateArray method

/* ********************************************************
   Pre Condition: an integer for the upper limit of the
   random number to generate.
   Post Condition: an integer in the range of 1 to limit
   ******************************************************** */

    public static int getRandomInt(int limit) {
        return (1 + (int)(Math.random() * limit));

    } // end of getRandomInt method

    public static int max(int highest) {

    } // end of class Array01
```

Comment: This is java, not javascript?

Comment: Let me give you a piece of advice. Don't make fields and method static just so you could run your code inside the main method.  If you don't have a legitimate reason to make fields and/or methods static, simply create an instance of your class inside the main method, and access them using the class instance.  Also, follow naming conventions (i.e. class names should be capitalized). Also, is there a question somewhere in your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merry Christmas.  I am in a giving mood today.  This is how you figure out the greatest value in the array:

```
public static int max(int[] array)
{
    int highest = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > highest)
        {
            highest = array[i];
        }
    }
    return highest;
}
```

Basically, assume the first stored value is the greatest value and compare it to the next value. If the next value is the greatest, assign to `highest` variable. Continue iterating through the array until you examine each and every value.  One pass, and you are done.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much. A great help and sorry for not leaving an actual question/

Comment: @binocencio don't forget to mark this as the answer if I indeed answered your question to your satisfaction.